# Postgresql Query on dates, excluding certain dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (Table name is "Emp_Play") in Postgres of employees' salaries.  Table structure is as below

```
Emp ID | PayDate  | Amount  |
0001   | 01/15/15 | 1450.00 |
0001   | 02/15/15 | 1455.00 |
0001   | 03/15/15 | 2100.00 |
0001   | 04/15/15 | 1450.00 |
```

Every employee has records such as this, with March being the "bonus" month.

I am trying to write an efficient query to average the employee pay amounts, but to exclude the date of the "bonus" month.  So far, I've come up with:

```
select avg("Amount") as AVG
from "Empl_Play" 
where "PayDate" between '01/01/2015' and '01/31/2015' and "PayDate" between '03/01/2015' and '12/31/2015';
```

Is there a simpler way to handle the queries so that certain conditions in the "PayDate" can be excluded, such as the "Bonus Month" of March?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select avg(Amount) as AVG
from Empl_Play
where extract(month from PayDate) <> 3 and
      extract(year from PayDate) = 2015;
```

Comment: or where DATE_PART('month',date) != 03;

Comment: @user993553 . . . That also works.  I just opted for the ANSI standard syntax.